# Why table scan when filtering on index?

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing

Question:  Why is the execution plan showing a table scan when filtering on an index?

Database Engine:  SQL Server 2019

Table Row Count: 4,000

I have read many articles on how non-clustered indexes are used in queries and dug through a couple of posts here, yet the behavior I see in the execution plan is not consistent with the theories.

Here's the simple table (a heap, I know, it should have a clustered index and normally it would, this is just to demonstrate the issue)

```
Create Table People (LastName NVarchar(50), FirstName NVarchar(50))

Create NONCLUSTERED INDEX Idx_LastName ON People (LastName)
```

The table is populated with 4,000 rows of data, no nulls.

If I execute the following query:

```
SELECT LastName FROM People WHERE LastName = 'Smith'
```

I get what I would expect, which is the Index Seek on Idx_LastName.

However, if I execute:

```
SELECT LastName, FirstName FROM People WHERE LastName = 'Smith'
```

The execution plan shows a Table Scan.  I infer that this is a "full table scan."

Why do I get a Table Scan when I am still only filtering on an indexed column and am only selecting values from the non-indexed column that specifically match the filtered subset of data - in this case lastnames matching 'smith'?

I understand that the query engine needs to scan the full set of firstnames that are associated with the lastname'Smith', but that pool of names should already be filtered because it's only all the first names associated with 'Smith' - which small subset of the total number of first names in the table.

So, why a full table scan?

Maybe it's not really a full table scan, but a partial table scan?  But, if that's the case, I have a hard time proving it.  Also, possibly 4,000 records is not enough to force the query engine to do an index seek, but I think it should be since just selecting on LastName results in a seek.

Comment: How many rows does your second query selects?

Comment: Make sure statistics are up to date.

Comment: Because your table has 4,000 rows. For a table that size it's quicker just to table scan. It makes sense to just use the index when the only data you are returning is in already the index. When you need more data than is in the index, it has to do a bookmark lookup afterwards and this is more work than just scanning the table

Comment: The query optimiser has determined that a full table scan is quicker/cheaper (in terms of cpu and/or IO) than a NC index seek with associated lookups. If you adjusted your NC index to include the FirstName column (either as a key column or as an included column) the optimiser would likely choose an index seek + lookups. Likewise, if you filtered on a LastName with much higher selectivity (i.e. is rarer, e.g. `WHERE LastName = 'Abbas'`), the optimiser might choose an index seek over a table scan, depending on the distribution of data across your table.

Comment: You can force the issue with a query hint. `SELECT LastName, FirstName FROM People WITH ( INDEX = Idx_LastName ) WHERE LastName = 'Smith'`. Not a good idea to do in production without good reason, but handy as an exercise to compare query plans.

Comment: Are your index stats up-to-date? I would expect the tipping point of seek versus scan to be less than 4,000 but YMMV.

Comment: Update, to answer the above questions in order:  #1 the number of rows selected or in the result set is 240.  #2 Stats were manually updated to make sure they were current.

Comment: #3 I was able to find a better test data generator this morning and I  increased the size of the table to 100,000 rows.  I still got the same behavior.  I think the optimiser will always do a table scan regardless of size. #4 I realize that I could create a Composite index using both first and last names and that would result in an index seek, but that doesn't answer the question concerning whether that single column index on last name, with a subset of first names should at some point be an index seek or index scan, not a full table scan.

Comment: Even more mystery:  I created a new test table now with 1 Milliion rows.  Same behavior.  But the mystery is when I do a SELECT * against the table with IO STATS ON it takes 35 seconds and claims 25,923 logical reads.  Fine.  Then I do SELECT LastName, FirstName and it takes only 1 second to run the query, BUT - guess what the logical read count is?  25,923.  how can both queries take such different times with the same read count?  Makes no sense.  (Physical reads is same also)